# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invoc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, error-handling

I am getting this error message below.  i have tried the surgestion on stackoverflow  and searched for other solution but they do not work. Can any one help with this?

```
>  setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Intermediates/tab project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/tab projectTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/tab projectTests.LinkFileList" -bundle_loader "/Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tab project.app/tab project" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o "/Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tab projectTests.octest/tab projectTests"

ld: file not found: /Users/stuart/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tab_project-evwkhgsuxscoetcgithrfgftafyk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tab project.app/tab project
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have added files to your solution/project via drag'n'drop.

Try this:

1. Select your project
2. Go to Build Phases Tab
3. Expand Compile Sources
4. Hit the "+" and add all the *.m files that you want included in your build

Comment: I added all the .M files to compile sources but sadly no luck

Comment: the only other thing that ever helped me was to remove the "Required device capabilities" items (if there are any), on the "Info" tab